Definition for orders corresponding to directed acyclic graphs (DAG)
My question
What is the name for a binary relation $R$ on $V$ that corresponds to a graph $G = (V,E)$ that is a directed acyclic (simple) graph?
Background
There is a bijection between simple directed graphs $G = (V,E)$ and binary relations $R$ on $V$  (so $R \subseteq V \times V$), via $(V,E) \mapsto E$ and the converse $R \mapsto (V,R)$.  In other words, if $G = (V,E)$ is the graph on $V$ corresponding to the binary relation $R$ on $V$, there is an edge from $x$ to $y$ in $G$ if and only if $x \sim_R y$.  (This is more obvious when it becomes clear that there being an edge from $x$ to $y$ means that $(x,y) \in E$, and that the term $x \sim_R y$ means $(x,y) \in R$.)
If $R$ is a binary relation on $V$ and $G = (V,E)$ is a simple directed graph, such that $R$ and $G$ correspond to each other via the above described bijection, we then have:

$R$ is a strict partial order on $V$ if and only if $G$ is a transitively closed directed acyclic (simple) graph.
$R$ is a linear order (total strict order) on $V$ if and only if $G$ is a transitively closed directed acyclic (simple) graph, whose induced undirected graph is strongly connected, which in turn is equivalent to $G$ being a directed acyclic (simple) graph, such that for all distinct $x,y \in V$, we have $x \sim_R y$ or $y \sim_R x$.
$R$ is ?? if and only if $G$ is a directed acyclic (simple) graph.

Notes

The set $\mathfrak S \subseteq \mathbb P (V\times V)$ of all binary relations on $V$ which correspond to a nontrivial directed acyclic (simple) graph, becomes a simplicial complex where the facets are the linear orders on $V$[1], and the vertices are tuples $(x,y) \in (V \times V) \setminus \Delta_V$, meaining $(x,y) \in V\times V$ with distinct $x,y \in V$, i.e. $x \neq y$.
This set $\mathfrak S$ can also be charactarized as the set of all nontrivial binary relations on $V$ that can be extended to a linear order on $V$[2].

[1] for finite $V$.  If $V$ is nonfinite and we do not assume the axiom of choice, there might be more facets than the linear orders.  If we assume that there exists at least one linear order on $V$, everything should be fine.  (I think)
[2] for finite $V$.  If $V$ is nonfinite and we do not assume the axiom of choice, then it is not always clear if we can extend the relation corresponding to a DAG to a linear order.  If we assume that there exists at least one linear order on $V$, everything should be fine.  (I think)

I believe the first relation you’re referring to (for an undirected graph $G = (V,E)$) is the one that’s known simply as adjacency. Indeed, $E$ may be interpreted as the adjacency relation (on $V$) for, or of, $G$. In the case of digraphs, do you mean reachability (or maybe its transitive reduction)?

Are you asking whether there exists some type of order that, as a class, corresponds to the DAGs?

I would simply call the relation a DAG, or whatever flavour of graph it corresponds to.

@PaulTanenbaum Indeed, the adjacency relation is precisely what I am talking about.  What I in essence stated in the background section is that for any graph we don't just receive an industed adjacency relation, but also this adjacency relation uniquely defines the graph, and any relation is a valid adjacency relation.  This "type" of order, or "class", obviously exists, I am just asking for a name of it or some other context or description in order theory outside of graph theory.

@NaïmFavier "or whatever flavour of graph it corresponds to":  well, for linear orders and partial strict orders, this is less convenient, it is more convenient to talk about it in order theory terms than in graph theory terms.  but for DAGs, it seems to be the other way around...  I am just wondering if there is some order-theoretic view on this

One of the basic features of an order is transitivity, which a graph doesn't impose. The closest is the reachability partial order (that is, reflexive, transitive and antisymmetric relation) associated to a DAG, but this loses some information.

@NaïmFavier yes, indeed, i think that is the main caveat:  orders usually always have transitivity, and i am asking for something without transitivity.

You're asking for something without transitivity, but the property you're asking for is a property that's all about the transitive closure of your relation, so it might be that "relation whose transitive closure is a strict partial order" is the most natural thing to say.
